# Box API: Create folder on behalf of another user

Tags: python-requests, box-api

I am able to create folder via `put` API call.
Now I am trying to use User impersonation to create a new folder giving following headers.

```
headers = { "Authorization" : "<token>", "As-User" : "237490238" }
```

It is always giving me 403 forbidden as response.

I also tried creating folder this way via POSTMAN giving `X-On-Behalf-Of` and `X-As-User` headers. The response is `201 ( created )` but `created_by` is not the user (with `id = '237490238'`) provided in headers.

Is it possible to have user impersonation in creating files/folders , creating shared links for files/folders via API?

Answer (score 2):

1: Your `Authorization` header is not formatted properly. The value needs to be prefixed by **Bearer**:

```
headers = { 
            "Authorization" : "Bearer <token>", 
            "As-User" : "237490238" 
          }
```

2: Ensure that the scope of your authorization token includes *Manage an enterprise*. This is required in order to use the `As-User` functionality.